# Getting length of objects in object - Last element is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using Firebase, I am pulling an array:

```
var lists = 
[{
    "members": {
      "R2sZlOcWW3YZLi6B0sSLjNmoIix2": "true",
      "y0dKatD5onPtmdtElBpeYvYaIMq1": "true"
    }
  },
  {
    "members": {
      "R2sZlOcWW3YZLi6B0sSLjNmoIix2": "true",
      "y0dKatD5onPtmdtElBpeYvYaIMq1": "true"
    }
  },
  ......
]
```

Using

```
  var chatCount = 0;
  var multMembersCount = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      let members = lists[i].members
      if (lists[i].chat) {
          chatCount += 1;
      }
      console.log(Object.keys(members).length)
  }
```

I am using `Object.keys(members).length` to find the length of each members object. The log is successfully writing to the console, however, at the end of the loop I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(members)')
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It looks like the last object does not have a `members` key. Post the full array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "`members ? Object.keys(members).length : 0`" instead of "`Object.keys(members).length`".

It will evaluate as `0` if `members` is an unexpected (falsy) item, or as the length if not.

Answer (score 0):

*Fix* is a relative term as there is no indication of what the desired behavior is. One way to avoid the error message is to resolve to a default value:

```
console.log(Object.keys(members||{}).length)
```

When `members` is `undefined` then the object `{}` will be used.